# Alter a 3D ndarray at the positions represented by a 2d ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

This is my first nontrivial use of numpy, and I'm having some trouble in one spot.

So, I have `colors`, a `(xsize + 2, ysize + 2, 3)` ndarray, and `newlife`, a `(xsize + 2, ysize + 2)` ndarray of booleans. I want to add a random value between -5 and 5 to all three values in colors at all positions where `newlife` is true. In other words `newlife` maps 2D vectors to whether or not I want to add a random value to the color in `colors` at that position.

I've tried a million variations on this:

```
colors[np.nonzero(newlife)] += (np.random.random_sample((xsize + 2,ysize + 2, 3)) * 10 - 5)
```

but I keep getting stuff like

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (589,3) (130,42,3) (589,3)`

How do I do this?

Comment: For the colors that should be changed, do you want to add the same random value to all three components, or a different random value to each component? I'm guessing the latter because of your code sample, but just checking to be sure.

Comment: The latter, yes; otherwise I'd just be changing the brightness of the color by a random amount, rather than making it a visibly different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
# example data
colors = np.random.randint(0, 100, (5,4,3))
newlife = np.random.randint(0, 2, (5,4), bool)

# create values to add, then mask with newlife
to_add = np.random.randint(-5,6, (5,4,3))
to_add[~newlife] = 0

# modify in place
colors += to_add
```

Answer (score 0):

This changes the colors in-place assuming `uint8` dtype. Both assumptions are not essential:

```
import numpy as np

n_x, n_y = 2, 2
colors = np.random.randint(5, 251, (n_x+2, n_y+2, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n_x+2, n_y+2), dtype=bool)

n_change = np.count_nonzero(mask)
print(colors)
print(mask)
colors[mask] += np.random.randint(-5, 6, (n_change, 3), dtype=np.int8).view(np.uint8)
print(colors)
```

The easiest way of understanding this is to look at the shape of `colors[mask]`.